# Cygwin, Theos: Error when make is run "/opt/theos/makefiles/common.mk:153: *** The "iphone" target is not supported on the "windows" platform. Stop."

Tags: ios, makefile, cygwin, theos

I have looked on countless forums and pages, only found one unsolved reddit post in /r/jailbreakdevelopers about this error(can't post link, not enough rep). I get this error when I run any make command in cygwin on my tweak project. Theos is installed according to [this](http://coolstar.org/theos.pdf) guide and I have followed [this](http://sharedinstance.net/2013/12/build-on-windows/) tutorial. I have tried reinstalling cygwin and theos, but nothing seems to work. I have $THEOS=/opt/theos, and
$THEOS_DEVICE_IP=(my iPhone 5's local ip)
Again, the error is
"/opt/theos/makefiles/common.mk:153: *** The "iphone" target is not supported on the "windows" platform. Stop."
I am running windows 10 and my device is an iPhone 5. Cygwin and theos are up to date.